# Cartesian Product of a Union and an Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given the Cartesian Product of an equation:

$(A \cap C) \times (B \cup A)$

As being $\{(5,1),(5,4),(6,1),(6,4)\}$

And the sets:

$B=\{1,9,4\}$ and $C=\{5,6,7,8\}$

And so I figure that $(A \cap C)=\{5,6\}$ and $(B \cup A)=\{1,4\}$

But regardless of the elements of the set $A$, surely $(B \cup A)$ must contain all three elements of $B$ and thusly $(B \cup A) \neq \{1,4\}$?

I am supposed to give an example of the set $A$ with the maximum cardinality, but given my understanding of set notation this is not possible, is it?

Comment: You are correct: it’s not possible, for the reason that you give.

Comment: Indeed, as written it is not solvable.  Perhaps there was a typo somewhere. Is it possible that your set was intended to be $(A\cap C)\times(B\cap A)$ ?  Or a dropped complement sign?

Comment: @GrahamKemp That would make more sense I realise, but that's not what it says on the question. I may add that as a note though.